# How to solve $x^5\equiv 3 \pmod{19}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How do I solve this equation:
$$x^5 \equiv  3\pmod{19} $$ where all I know is Fermat's Little Theorem and operations on multiplicative group $\mathbb Z_p^*$?

Comment: So you know $x^5$ and $x^{18}$ modulo $19$. Luckily, $\gcd(5,18)=1$ so it should be possible to work out $x^1$ from these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $x^5=3$, we can seek a solution to $5k\equiv 1\bmod 18$ and then, using Fermat's Little Theorem, we will have

$x\equiv x^{5k}\equiv 3^k\bmod 19$

So how to solve $5k\equiv 1\bmod 18$?  Multiplying by $4$ leads to $20k\equiv 2k\equiv 4$ and thus $k\in\{2,11\}$.  Clearly $k\equiv 11\bmod 18$ is the correct solution, the other one having become an extraneous root because we used a multiplier that divides zero $\bmod 18$.

So $x\equiv 3^{11}\bmod 19$ which can be figured in either of two ways.  First, by the standard squaring and multiplication approach:

$3^2\equiv 9, 3^4\equiv 9^2\equiv 5, 3^5\equiv 3×5\equiv15, 3^{10}\equiv 15^2\equiv 16, \color{blue}{3^{11}\equiv 3×16\equiv10}$.

Alternatively, if we recognize that $3$ is not a quadratic residue $\bmod 19$, we can render

$3^{11}\equiv 3^2×3^9\equiv 9×(-1)\color{blue}{\equiv 10}$.

There is a nice way to check this result from the repeating decimal block for $1/19$.  To wit:

$1/19=0.\overline{052631578947368421}$.

Shifting the decimal point five places to the right should give the repeating block for $10^5/19$, which begins with $15$ and thus is clearly also the repeating block for $3/19$.

Answer (score 0):

First note that

- $19$ is a prime number.
- $19$ does not divide $x$ (why?).

If we take the $4$th power , we obtain

$$
x^{20} \equiv 3^4 = 81 \equiv 5 \pmod{19}
$$

From the fermat little theorem we get
$$
x^{20} = x \cdot x^{19} \equiv x^2 \equiv 5\pmod{19}
$$
So we are looking for $x$ such that
$$
x^2 = 19\cdot n + 5
$$
If we try the first numbers we discover that for $n=5$ the RHS becames $100$, hence $x=10$ solves the equation.

Comment: did you mean "$19$ does not divide $x$" when you wrote "$x$ does not divide $19$"?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the above one as $x^2\equiv 5\pmod {19}$ we have $x^2\equiv 81\pmod {19}$ and therefore, the solutions are of the form $19k- 9$.

and for $x=19k+9$ is not the solution because, when we plug this into the original modulo, with the fact that $19\not|(9^5-3)$, the equivalence is not possible.

Comment: Not $\pm$.  You have to choose the correct sign.  See my argument for why we got an extraneous root.

Comment: Ok, the solutions are of the form $19k-9$.

Comment: Now you have to prove that you have chosen wisely.  Why isn't it $19k+9$?

Comment: Plug it into $x^5\equiv 3\pmod {19}$, I think and $19\not|(9^5-3)$

Comment: Say (and prove) so within your answer.  You might want to note that $9^5$ would be equal to $3^{10}$

Comment: Sorry for that, my bad, I'm very new here.