# Solve $x^{67}\equiv 5\pmod{101}$.

Tags: solution-verification, modular-arithmetic

Solve $x^{67}\equiv 5\pmod{101}$.

I used this [How to solve $x^5\equiv 3 \pmod{19}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3687978/how-to-solve-x5-equiv-3-pmod19) to solve this problems, I would like to make a solution verfication.

I'll solve the equation $67k\equiv 1 \pmod{100}$.

Multiply by $3$ ,$201k\equiv 3 \pmod{100} \implies k\equiv 3 \pmod{100}\implies k=3$.

So $x=5^3\pmod{101}\equiv 24\pmod{101}$.

Is my solution correct ?

Thanks !

Comment: Looks ok to me. For full credit you probably should explicitly mention that 101 is a prime :-)

Comment: Yes, it is correct, Please only ask SV questions if you have a *mathematical* question about a *specific* step in your proof. Which step do you doubt, and why? $ $   Note $\bmod 100\!:\ \dfrac{1}{67}\equiv \dfrac{1}{-33}\equiv \dfrac{1}{-33}\dfrac{3}3\equiv \dfrac{3}1\ $ by [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242).

Comment: Remember, it is easy to check your result.  You can do it by hand, or use something like [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=24%5E67+mod+101).

Comment: See [this Linked list](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/3187793?lq=1) for *many* more worked examples.